# SharePoint 2010 - Delete user profile

Tags: 2010, user-profile, delete, organization-browser

Organization Browser in mysites was still displaying users who were disabled or deleted from Active Directory. We did not turn on the SharePoint 2010 My Site Cleanup Timer Job because it sends emails to managers. I am still trying figure out how to avoid sending emails but in the mean time I read somewhere that we can delete the user profiles by searching in Central Admin - Manage user profiles for "Profiles missing from import".

I tried to delete a user profile who I know was no longer with the company and after the deletion, the Organization Browser for the manager of the deleted user stopped working.

Did anyones else face this issue and do you have any solutions?

Comment: Is your user profile sync working as expected?

Comment: Try to run the Full profile sync and also search crawl for People.

Comment: Yes User profile sync is working as expected.

Comment: I did a user profile synchronization, that did not resolve the issue. How do you do a search crawl for People?

Comment: crawl the mysites web app.

Answer (score 1):

This issue resolved itself after an hour or so. I believe the search crawler refreshes or something of that sort.

Thank you all for trying to help.